# DoubleClickSearch conversion API request error

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, double-click-advertising

I have the following code which uses the Google.Apis.Doubleclicksearch.v2 library and which fails on the last line:

```
class Program
{

    private const string Account = "<<ID>>@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    private const string P12Path = @"<<APICert>>.p12";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(P12Path, "notasecret",
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
            X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(Account)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { DoubleclicksearchService.Scope.Doubleclicksearch }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        DoubleclicksearchService service = new DoubleclicksearchService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "MyApp",
            ApiKey = "<<APIKEY>>"
        });

        int isoDate = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyymmdd"));
        var conversionRequest = service.Conversion.Get(<<AgencyID>>,
            <<AdvertiserID>>,
            <<EngineAccountID>>,
            isoDate, 10,
            isoDate, 0);

        conversionRequest.Execute();

    }
}
```

The error is:

> Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   An internal error occurred. Please retry your request at a later time. Details: [Invalid id] [500]

Answer (score 1):

Date formatting somewhat suspect :

> int isoDate = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("**yyyymmdd**"));
>
> int isoDate = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("**yyyyMMdd**"));

In addition, DS auth requires oAUth2: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/authorizing

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes, that and using Outh2 instead of authenticating by certificate, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message says Invalid Id, double check that your Agency, Advertiser and Engine IDs are correct. If they are then maybe the Account your using does not have access to the Agency or Advertiser or Engine? Can you call any other API methods with the same Account and Agency or Advertiser or Engine that work?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have checked those. I am migrating the script from Python which uses these values. The only other difference is that I am authenticating using a certificate (whereas the Python script uses an oAuth client) https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth